# All my windows I open in ubuntu 13.04 are invisible

Tags: screen

Whenever I boot Ubuntu 13.04 from the GRUB screen everything is normal and, when I get to the login screen everything is still normal. Then, as usual (I am new), I open the Terminal to try and learn more about how to use it. However, all the screen shows, is my desktop.

I check to see if I opened Terminal so I open another window but still nothing. Everything is like this, except the unity launcher, (unity it self is fine) and the Administrator screen, where you put in your password like sudo.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me what the screen looks like when you log in please.

Comment: @SimplySimon After i log in it look like the desktop i added then a Test folder i created with the mkdir command in the terminal when i was messing around and with the unity launcher and search on the left and nothing else. I hope that helps.

Comment: @EdManet I agree that would be a cool band name. XD